# white input background on iphone, can't get it away

Tags: ios, css, mobile

Is anyone familiar with a white background on an input on iPhone ? 
I am trying to make an input without any styling, so with a transparent background.
Everywhere it works fine except on the iphone.

What I've tried already is

```
background: none;
background-color: none; or background-color: transparent; (tried both)
da
-webkit-appearance:none;
```

none seems to work. Anyone knows what the problem might be?

[image]

Comment: Couldn't understand your issue. Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Do you want a transparent background here?

Comment: yes, transparent. Or if that impossible on ios just a blue background (wich i also tried). I will edit my question

Comment: Provide me your code or create a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ if possible

Comment: I have also given a solution try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in this case was to put

```
all: revert !important;
```

before any other input styling. It probably got overwritten by something in the framework I use.

Comment: If that was the case then assigning an ID would have worked. By the way happy you problem is solved :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried it on an iPhone 6 with iOS 10, real device and simulator, using

```
<input style="background: transparent; border: none;" type="text" />
```

There doesn't seem to be a problem with that. The input is fully transparent.

Please check the inspector to see if any other style declaration is overwriting yours.
Do this in the "computed styles" section of the inspector and check the background or background-color property. It will tell you which declaration is used to render the element. You can jump directly into this declaration by using the little arrow, see the screenshot from chrome inspector

[chrome inspector screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQ4PQ.png)

Try to avoid using !important because this will mess up your code and it is not a good practice. Use better qualified selectors instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use `background: transparent!important;` or apply id to the input field like:

```
input type="text" id="search">
```

**Css:**

```
input#search{
  background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. There was something in the framework overwriting this i gueass since putting all: revert; just before did the trick.